# First line in file is not always printed in bash script

Tags: bash, output-redirect

I have a bash script that prints a line of text into a file, and then calls a second script that prints some more data into the same file. Lets call them script1.sh and script2.sh. The reason it's split into two scripts, is because I have different versions of script2.sh.

script1.sh:

```
rm -f output.txt
echo "some text here" > output.txt
source script2.sh
```

script2.sh:

```
./read_time >> output.txt
./run_program
./read_time >> output.txt
```

Variations on the three lines in script2.sh are repeated.

This seems to work most of the time, but every once in a while the file output.txt does not contain the line "some text here". At first I thought it was because I was calling script2.sh like this: `./script2.sh`. But even using `source` the problem still occurs.
The problem is not reproducible, so even when I try to change something I don't know if it's actually fixed.

What could be causing this?

Edit:
The scripts are very simple. script1 is exactly as you see here, but with different file names. script 2 is what I posted, but then the same 3 lines repeated, and `./run_program` can have different arguments. I did a grep for the output file, and for `>` but it doesn't show up anywhere unexpected.

The way these scripts are used is that script1 is created by a program (the only difference between the versions is the `source script2.sh` line. This script1.sh is then run on a different computer (linux on an FPGA actually) using ssh. Before that is done, the output file is also deleted using ssh. I don't know why, but I didn't write all of this. Also, I've checked the code running on the host. The only mention of the output file is when it is deleted using ssh, and when it is copied back to the host after the script1 is done.

Edit 2:
I finally managed to make the problem reproducible at a reasonable rate by stripping script2.sh of everything but a single line printing into the file. This also let me do the testing a bit faster. Once I had this I got the problem between 1 and 4 times for every 10 runs. Removing the command that was deleting the file over ssh before the script was run seems to have solved the problem. I will test it some more to be sure, but I think it's solved. Although I'm still not sure why it would be a problem. I thought that the ssh command would not exit before all the remove commands were executed.

Comment: is output.txt on a remote filesystem? or an NFS mounted filesystem?

Comment: Thanks for the help. It turns out ssh was started in a non-blocking way. I changed it to blocking and now it works as expected. I was ready to put in a check to see if the first line was printed, but knowing the real cause and fixing that is much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell without seeing the real code. Most likely explanation is that you have a typo, `>` instead of `>>`, somewhere in one of the script2.sh files.

To verify this, set `noclobber` option with `set -o noclobber`. The shell will then terminate when trying to write to existing file with `>`.

Another possibility, is that the file is removed under certain rare conditions. Or it is damaged by some command which can have random access to it - look for commands using this file without `>>`. Or it is used by some command both as input and output which step on each other - look for the file used with `<`.

Lastly, you can have a racing condition with a command outputting to the file in background, started before that `echo`.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that's not the case. When I notice the problem and run the same script again, it disappears. Also just to be sure I checked some of the scripts where I had noticed this, and there are no missing `>` in there. I'd like to post the code of course, but I can't.

Comment: Then there is the universal advice: start simplifying your scripts, removing unrelated code, until it is either obvious what's happening, or you can post them in your question.

Comment: Also check my additions to the answer.

Comment: I tried setting noclobber, but I get no errors. I'm thinking it has to be something that randomly deletes the file, but I can't think of anything that would do that. BTW, script 1 is complete. The only thing I changes are the names, and the text printed into the file. script 2 basically calls different programs and prints the start and end times into a file. none of the programs accesses output.txt. each version of script 2 calls either different programs, or the same program with different arguments. In all cases the get_time program is the only one that the output is redirected to the file.

Comment: Also, because I can't reproduce the problem reliably, I have no way of knowing what the minimal case is that causes the problem.

Comment: OK, then remove these commands that you think are the only ones outputting to that file (except the echo). And see if it makes any difference. If not, then there is something else. Try making the file read-only after that echo. And, BTW, find a way to reproduce this reliably. Make a test running this program and verifying that file after it completes. Then run this test a hundred, a thousand times until it starts reproducing reliably.

Answer (score 1):

Can you grep all your scripts for 'output.txt'? What about scripts called inside read_time and run_program?

It looks like something in one of the script2.sh scripts must be either overwriting, truncating or doing a substitution on output.txt.

For example,there could be a '> output.txt' burried inside a conditional for a condition that rarely obtains. Just a guess, but it would explain why you don't always see it.

This is an interesting problem. Please post the solution when you find it!

Comment: Grepping the scripts only gives results like `./read_time >> output.txt`.
I've also searched through sources of other programs running at that time and none have any mention of output.txt.

Comment: a related idea would be to change such a generic output name to something much less likely to be used by by any other program, anywhere in the O.P.s environment, like `special_testCase.$$.txt.output`, or some such craziness. Good luck to all.

Comment: The actual file name is sw_events.log, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: OK, so if script1.sh is always being run, we know the text is written to the file, so something must be removing the file or changing it. Maybe 'output.txt' is in a config file? Or maybe one of the scripts dynamically creates a variable that contains 'output.txt'? For example file=`ls | grep 'output'` ( a trivial example I know). Can you grep for rm? Or all '> '?